# Blank game screen on Level 19

Tags: untrusted

After loading Level 19, documentObjectMadness.js, the game screen turns completely black.  All input seems to be ignored, but sound still works.

[image: Blank]

If I hit "Reset", I can see my character (green) in the top left and a different character (red) in the bottom right.

[image: Resetting]

Is this the expected functionality?  I have not found anywhere in the code window that can be edited, so I'm not sure how I might progress on this level.  In case it matters, I am using Firefox 28.0 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, as we've just discovered, it looks like level 19 doesn't render on any browser except Chrome.

It's a known issue and we're working hard to fix it (https://github.com/AlexNisnevich/untrusted/issues/105).

In the meantime, there is a sort of a "cheat" you can do: click within the blank game screen and keep pressing the Up key. Eventually you will move on to the next level.

Comment: That sucks that it's a bug... I kinda wanted to see it lol. Thanks for letting us know though!

Comment: Its one of the weakest levels to be honest. I had a click around for a bit to see what happened before looking into or writing code and found that I'd hit the next level without even knowing what I was looking at or what the victory condition was.

Comment: At the very least I was hoping for an animation indicating I'd caught the bad guy. The level transition (at least in Firefox) is too abrupt.

Comment: The level should work now on all browsers. We're currently working on making the level more interesting. (I admit that it's rather weak in its current state.)

Comment: @BadgerPriest: is there a place to give feedback on this sort of thing? I'm not sure these comments is a suitable place. However, just in case how about having a class on a dom element that you cannot move into needing you to right code to redo those? Or maybe the other way round and adding classes that your target can't move into allowing you to trap them. One of the main reasons it was a bit weak was no coding needed which at level 19 seemed weird. :) Generally love the game though. :)

Comment: @Chris: The absolute best place to give feedback on the game is on its GitHub issues page: https://github.com/AlexNisnevich/untrusted/issues

Comment: The "press up" hack no longer works in recent versions of the game.