# Help with Level 16's lazers

Tags: untrusted

In Untrusted, how can I get past the lasers? I'm assuming I need to use my phone, but even removing the strokes of the lazers still makes me get hit by them.

[image]

Comment: Alternative solution: close the `createLaser` definition, then redefine `createLaser` to not do anything.

Comment: @user2357112 post as an answer if it worked for you

Comment: @user2357112 That solution no longer works in recent versions of untrusted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the code below to display the lasers (in their correct color) and also give your phone the ability to change your color.  As you move, use `Q` to cycle through your colors until you can pass through the lasers.  Cycle goes: (Green ->) Red -> Yellow -> Teal -> Red

```
var ctx = map.getCanvasContext();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.strokeStyle = color;
ctx.lineWidth = 5;
ctx.moveTo(x1, y1);
ctx.lineTo(x2, y2);
ctx.stroke();

map.getPlayer().setPhoneCallback(function(){
    if(player.getColor()=='red')
        player.setColor('yellow');
    else if(player.getColor()=='yellow')
        player.setColor('teal');
    else
        player.setColor('red');
});
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I hate how I find out the answer *just* as you're posting them! Lol

Comment: @CanadianLuke Ask the question, get an answer.  I'm [stuck on level 19](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/163618/42984) for now.

Comment: You just wanting the extra rep? Good, cause I'm stuck on the next one now lol

Answer (score 3):

override

```
getRandomInt = function(){return 600;};
```

and all lasers are drawn off screen/out the way

Answer (score 2):

If you are too lazy to think about a true solution... :)

```
// ... ctx.stroke(); 
map.getPlayer().killedBy = function() { };
```

Answer (score 2):

or just change the color of all lasers

> color=player.getColor();